# How can I create a persistent list of globally accesible objects queried from threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, promise, future

I've been trying to get a persistent object from a thread for hours.
I want to write a shared library in C++ that starts a persistent loop in a function.
In the following code snippets there is a class called Process. Process initializes a TCP/IP interface to read and write data from a Simulink model.

This is only for declaration and should not be important for this problem, but now you know what I talk about when mentioning the processes.

#### main.cpp

I know, it looks kinda ugly/unprofessional, but I'm fairly new to C++..

```cpp
// frustrated attempt to make everything persistent
static vector<std::thread> processThreads;
static ProcessHandle processHandle;
static vector<std::promise<Process>> promiseProcess;
static vector<std::future<Process>> futureProcess;

EXPORT int initializeProcessLoop(const char *host, int port)
{
    std::promise<Process> promiseObj;
    futureProcess.push_back(std::future<Process>(promiseObj.get_future()));
    processThreads.push_back(std::thread(&ProcessHandle::addProcess, processHandle, host, port, &promiseProcess[0]));

    Process val = futureProcess[0].get();

    processHandle.handleList.push_back(val);

    return (processHandle.handleList.size() - 1);
}
```

#### ProcessHandle.cpp

The addProcess function from ProcessHandle creates the Process that should be persistent, adds it to a static vector member of ProcessHandle and passes the promise to the execution loop.

```cpp
int ProcessHandle::addProcess(const char *address, int port, std::promise<Process> * promiseObj) {
    Process process(address, port);

    handleList.push_back(process);
    handleList[handleList.size() - 1].exec(promiseObj);
    return handleList.size() - 1;
}
```

To the main problem now...

If I change "initializeProcessLoop" to include:

```cpp
    if(processHandle.handleList[0].isConnected())
    {
        processHandle.handleList[0].poll("/Compare To Constant/const");
    }
```

after i've pushed "val" to the processHandle.handleList everything works fine and I can poll the data as it should be.

If I instead poll it from - for examle - the main function, the loop crashes inside of the "initializeProcessLoop" because "Process val" is reassigned (?) with futureProcess[0].get().

How can I get the Process variable and the threaded loop to be consistent after the function returns?

If there are any questions to the code (and I bet there will be), feel free to ask. Thanks in advance!

PS: Obligatory "English is not my native language, please excuse any spelling errors or gibberish"...

Comment: You will need to review the material in C++ book that discusses inter-thread sequencing, and implement thread-safe access to your global variables, using mutexes and condition variables. None of the global access shown here is thread-safe, and it's no surprise that the whole thing fails miserably. This is a complicated topic that cannot be fully explained in one or two paragraph on stackoverflow. C++ is hard, and stackoverflow is not really a replacement for a C++ textbook, so you'll have to be referred there, for more information.

Comment: Well, these could be the buzz words that I am missing the whole time. Doing this for the first time I didn't even knew how to google any more than I already did. Thank you, I'll look into this!

Comment: Well, the real mistake is trying to learn C++ from Google. You won't learn much C++ from Google searches and random Youtube videos. C++ is the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today. The C++ standard runs to nearly 2000 pages. It's going to take very many Google searches to find everything, if anything, that covers everything. The only realistic way to learn C++, and learn C++ correctly, is from a well-established textbook. You are free to ignore this, but at some point you will realize that this is true, but only after wasting months and years on Google searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, first I have to declare, that the coding style above and following are by any means not best practice.

While Sam Varshavchik is still right with how to learn C++ the right way, just changing

```cpp
Process val = futureProcess[0].get();
```

to

```cpp
static Process val = futureProcess[0].get();
```

did the job.

To be clear: don't do this. It's a quick fix but it will backfire in the future. But I hope that it'll help anyone with a similar problem.

If anyone has a better solution (it can't get any worse, can it?), feel free to add your answer to this question.